# What open source projects would you say has well written Jasmine / Jasmine-Jquery tests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tdd, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to learn how to test a jquery plugin that I'm about to write.

I was wondering if there were any Jasmine, Jasmine-jquery github(or any other open source code) projects that have really well written Jasmine tests that I could read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start at [https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Who's-using-jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Who%27s-using-jasmine)